# http2 domain sharding without hurting performance

Tags: cdn, sharding, http2

Most articles consider using domain sharding as hurting performance but it's actually not entirely true. A single connection can be reused for different domains at certain conditions:

- they resolve to the same IP
- in case of secure connection the same certificate should cover both domains

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-9.1.1

Is that correct? Is anyone using it?

And what about CDN? Can I have some guarantees that they direct a user to the same server (IP)?

Answer (score 2):

Yup that’s one of the benefits of HTTP/2 and in theory allows you to keep sharding for HTTP/1.1 users and automatically unshard for HTTP/2 users.

The reality is a little more complicated as always - due mostly to implementation issues and servers resolving to different IP addresses as you state. This blog post is a few years old now but describes some of the issues: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/08/18/http2-connection-coalescing/. Maybe it’s improved since then, but would imagine issues still exist. Also new features like the [ORIGIN frame](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8336) should help but are not widely supported yet.

I think however it’s worth revisiting the assumption that sharding is actually good for HTTP/1.1. The costs of setting up new connections (DNS lookup, TCP setup, TLS handshake and then the actual sending HTTP messages) are not immaterial and studies have shown the 6 connection browser limit is really used never mind adding more by sharding. Concatenation, spriting and inlining are usually much better options and these can still be used for HTTP/2. Try it on your site and measure is the best way of being sure of this!

Incidentally it is for for these reasons (and security) that I’m less keen on using common libraries (e.g. jquery, bootstrap...etc.) from their CDNs instead of hosted locally. In my opinion the performance benefit of a user already having the version your site uses already cached is over stated.

With al these things, HTTP/1.1 will still work without sharded domains. It may (arguably) be slower but it won’t break. But most users [are likely on HTTP/2](https://caniuse.com/#feat=http2) so is it really worth adding the complexity for the minority’s of users? Is this not a way of progressively enhancing your site for people on modern browsers (and encouraging those not, to upgrade)? For larger sites (e.g. Google, Facebook... etc.) the minority may still represent a large number of users and the complexity is worth it (and they have the resources and expertise to deal with it) for the rest of us, my recommendation is not to shard, to upgrade to new protocols like HTTP/2 when they become common (like it is now!) but otherwise to keep complexity down.